# Swift: How to keep track of and communicate scores between scenes in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am building a game in spritekit that has a three scenes: main menu, play scene, and game over scene.

I need the main menu to display the high score, the play scene to display a current score, and the game over scene to display the high score and the player's score from their last play through.

How would I transfer this score data between scenes and how would I keep track of a player's high score?

Looking around I've found stuff about NSUserDefaults but I don't know how to implement it properly.

Admittedly I am a novice at SpriteKit and coding in general so I need very specific instructions.

Sorry if this question is rather broad. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSUserDefaults is a great way to keep track of scores.

To save the high score:

```
let x : Int = 45 // This int is your high score
var myString = String(x) // This String is you high score as a String

var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

defaults.setObject(myString, forkey : "High_Score") // Saving the String to NSUserDefaults
```

To access the high score:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

var HighScore = defaults.objectForKey("High_Score") // Retrieving your high score as a String
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. So would I put that in my viewcontroller? And if so where in my viewcontroller would I put it? I also need to access this data from multiple scenes so how would I do that?

Comment: You can put the second part wherever in your program you want to access the data and the first part to save your highscore (wherever you do that).